# How to get Views in activity A animate to activity B's layout hierarchy?

Tags: android, animation

I have two activities A & B. When I click on a view in A, I would like the clicked view to move to the top and expand into the layout defined by activity B.

Is this possible?

One of the ideas I had was to call a method that could measure B's layout hierarchy while still in activity A, animate the clicked view in A to B's layout positions, then expand/crossfade A to B. However, I'm having trouble trying to get B's layout measurements while still in A.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Google I/O 2013 A Moving Experience](http://youtu.be/ihzZrS69i_s)

This session introduce similar example. You can fix the image location of Activity B or sending animation result layout from activity A to B using intent extra.